# VS Code: How to clear search sidebar results?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After using search sidebar to find files in a folder, the results are displayed. I couldn't find a way to clear the search results and revert back to original search view other than restarting the app.

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/hahYdG)

VS Code version: 1.17.2

Answer (score 1):

The right most icon on the top of the search pane is a clear search button.

[image]

Comment: I expected that button to clear the results, the search field, "files to include" and "files to exclude" fields too. It seems developers didn't intent to do that however.